# I can not get value from the controller (Spring MVC)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I'm a beginner in spring programming. (i'm not good in english)
I have a problem that I can not get value from the controller.
My previous jsp worked fine, but I did not work with this project about a week then back to work, and i founded all jsp that I created after can not get value from the controller. But my previous jsp page worked fine.
I have seen on the same question and they said the error focus on version in web.xml but I dont have this error because the previous page jsp is still work fine.

- Web.xml

  ```
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
  ```
- JSP file

  ```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

  <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


  <html>
  <head>
  <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

  </head>
  <body> <h1>${check}</h1> </body> </html>
  ```
- Controller

  ```
  @Controller
   public class SingleController {
      @RequestMapping(value="/single", method=RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView single() {
          ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
          mav.setViewName("single");
          mav.addObject("check", "123");
          return mav;
      }    
   }
  ```

Comment: Please post your code (not the image of code).

Comment: post your web.xml and servelet.xml

Comment: getting any error..?

Comment: no error, since i back to this project, any new jsp does not receive value from controller, but the previous jsp work fine

Comment: Ensure that you correctly configured ViewResolver in Spring

Comment: LOLLLL, i import ModelAndView is portlet (not servlet) ...... This problem was resovled